# When is the TypeScript compiler typically employed to to produce JavaScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Is typescript compiling an pre-code deployment tool, or a run time tool (in its typical usage!). If it's a run time tool is the compiling done client side (probably not cause you'd have to send down the compiler, right?) or server side (I'd guess as a first-hit and then cache type thing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should generate the final Javascript files ready for deployment as part of the build process.

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio, it is possible to setup TypeScript to "Compile on Save", it is configured in project options under TypeScript Build

Answer (score 1):

typescript compiles down to es3 by default for maximum portability. Compiling occurs during the build process client-side as LIoyd mentioned.

Typescript is mainly for compiling but in chrome and firefox there is the capability to do run-time debugging on the original source files

Answer (score 0):

The whole goal of 'typed' languages is to catch syntax and type related problems before runtime, at so called 'compile-time'. You want such feedback early while coding, typically on file save in order to fix the problems.